# How to create a .cmpbitmap file from a regular JPEG

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm trying to create a .cpbitmap file using Objective C, can anyone point me in the right direction? It's the same file format that apple uses to store WallPapers. Any help would be greatly appreciated